# MySql group_concat as list of integers, not strings

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a sub query, which will be used in another sub queries "In" statement.  I want to select a group of values and create a coma delimited list from the select.  The code I have seems to work except, it's being returned as a string list but I need an integer list.  Here is what I have:

```
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(t.MyCol SEPARATOR  ',')
 FROM 
activities_themes t
where t.PrimaryCol= 87
GROUP BY t.PrimaryCol
```

Like I said, this returns the expected result, but as a string.  When I copy the result and paste it into a text editor, there are single quotes around the entire string.  Anyone know how I can return the result as integers without the quotes around it?  This needs to be for a SQL statement, not a stored procedure.

**ADDED**

This is the full statement:

```
SELECT
themes.Theme 
from 
themes as themes 
where 
themes.ThemesID in 
(
    SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(t.MyCol SEPARATOR  ',')
     FROM 
    activities_themes t
    where t.PrimaryCol= 87
    GROUP BY t.PrimaryCol
)
```

If I run the inner sub query, i get a list like this:  2,3,5,7,8.  If I then replace the sub query with the copied list, it works fine.  I get a list of values.  But, if I run the code as it is, it will only return the first value for the sub query.

Comment: There shouldn't be quotes around the values.

Comment: can you not just put the query in the 'IN' part: ...WHERE something IN (SELECT ...)

Comment: That's what I did, but it only returns the first value.  I'll append my question to reflect this:

Comment: You mean you have quotes _within_ the string, around the commas, or only two quotes, at the beginning and at the end? Around sounds like the latter to me. Or, can you show us what you get and what you'd like to get?

Comment: Daniel, only a around the beginning and end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about, in line with @dwjw's comment, if you just run:

```
SELECT
themes.Theme 
from 
themes as themes 
where 
themes.ThemesID in 
(
    SELECT 
    t.MyCol
     FROM 
    activities_themes t
    where t.PrimaryCol= 87
)
```